# Dropped ssh/X session, how to pickup where left off?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel, xorg

I am VPN from a Linux box to another. I log in to the other box with ssh -X. I open an X window/program in an attempt to do a software installation. The painful truth is that this software cannot be installed from the shell.  Anyway, all is well but slow. However, the VPN session will periodically drop and the installation is frozen.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how after I re-login to VPN could I restore that ssh/X session? Or, is that impossible?

```
ssh -X user@192.168.0.1
./setup.sh &
[1] 1084
```

Continue work by X application.
VPN drops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot reconnect to a session you already lost. You can only kill its processes.

But if you are preparing for future, you can use `tmux` or `screen` for terminal-based programs and `xpra` ([this fork](http://xpra.org/)) for X11 ones.

```
tmux
tmux ls
tmux attach

xpra start :100 --start=xterm
xpra attach :100
```

Comment: If it's not finished immediately, never run it outside `screen`. Should be in the `motd` on all systems.

Comment: Because all users read the motd, yes.

Comment: Probably not, but seeing it upon every login might still have an effect -- at least for command-line access. I see the MOTDs of several systems every day.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use nomachine NX or Freenx if ist available for your distro. Its also much faster than ssh +X forwarding.
 Another option is teamviewer or vnc.